# Ruby 'require' and File Suffixes

Tags: ruby, include

I have two files:

1. A Ruby file that contains both a class definition and a sample script. This is simply called '*foo*' since I would like to run it as an executable in certain circumstances.
2. A Ruby test script named '*bar.rb*' that tests the tests that methods of '*foo*.'

When trying to include '*foo*' in '*bar.rb*' I encounter a require error:

```
gem_original_require': no such file to load -- foo (LoadError)
```

However, if I rename '*foo*' to '*foo.rb*' the problem disappears! From my understanding, the Ruby 'require' method should be able to load data even from non '*.rb' files.

Is there a way to import the functionality of '*foo*' without changing the file suffix? Does anyone have an explanation for the behavior exhibited?

Comment: clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file that `require` loads has to have an extension that is explicitly stated in the argument of `require`, or otherwise, be either `.rb` or `.so`.

Solution for you is to use `load` instead.